# Create two foreign key constraints with on update/delete cascade

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, ssms, check-constraints

Example of database (SQL Server):

```
Table A
   -colA (PK, int)

Table B
   -ColB (FK, int) --> points to Table X

Table C
   -ColAC (PK, FK, int not null) --> points to Table A
   -ColBC (PK, FK, int not null) --> points to Table B
```

Table C's primary key is both ColAC and ColBC. Each column has foreign key that points to a different table. I need to have ON UPDATE/DELETE CASCADE constraints on both foreign keys for Table C. So when either Table A or B has changes then it is cascaded in Table C.

Table A and B are already in use. I can create Table C with only either one of the constraints but not both, this will return an error message. How do I create both FK constraints?

Example of SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_C (
    ColAC INT NOT NULL,
    ColBC INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (
    ColAC,
    ColBC
    )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE Table_C WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY (ColAC)
REFERENCES Table_A (ColA)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

--The second constraint will always fail (does not matter which one is first).
ALTER TABLE Table_C WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY (ColBC)
REFERENCES Table_B (ColB)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Error message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint .... on table 'Table_C' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Learn to do your own research and debugging. That error is a common topic (search on "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths") and you can find many discussions about the solution. Short answer - you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for two different tables, instead of single TableC

- Table C1
  -ColAC (PK, FK, int not null) --> points to Table A
- Table C2
  -ColBC (PK, FK, int not null) --> points to Table B

Now, you can have UNION ALL between these two tables

```sql
CREATE VIEW vw_TableC
AS
SELECT ColAC, 'TableA' as parent ... FROM TableC1
UNION ALL
SELECT ColBC, 'TableB' as parent ... FROM TableC2
```